# Python print output not appearing when called from bash

Tags: python, bash

Here is a minimal working example:

I have a python script `test.py` that contains:

```py
print("Hello")
```

and I have a bash script `test.sh` that calls that python function

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
python test.py
```

and when I run `test.sh` from terminal there is no output.

Based on a few similar questions, I have tried appending `sys.stdout.flush` and calling `python -u` instead, but there is still no output.

How do I get the output of `print` to show up?

**Edit**

In more complicated examples, how do I ensure that python print statements appear when called within a bash script? And ensure that those statements can be appropriately redirected with, e.g. `&>` operators?

(Also, I tried searching for a while before asking, but couldn't find a question that addressed this exactly. Any links to more thorough explanations would be greatly appreciated!)

Comment: Try adding \n at the end of the string and see if that makes any difference. Likely the string is written but overwritten by the shell prompt

Comment: Is it the problem of python or bash? Have you tried launching it in terminal? Also try changing `python` to `python3`

Comment: Try `python ./test.py`.

Comment: @VincentFourmond I tried the '\n' and that didn't work.

Comment: @DanielWalker The files are actually in different directories so my actual command in the bash script is more like `python /home/daniel/test.py`

Comment: Try that then.  I can't remember the details but I think I've run into a similar problem before when naming a file "test.py".

Comment: @sudden_appearance My standard `python` command already points to python3. But...I tried changing it anyway, no success. 

When I directly run `python test.py` from the terminal, I do see the output. It's only within the script that I don't see it.

Comment: 1. Are you sure that you are running the right shell script? Try putting an `echo` call in it. Do you get that output? 2. If you run the Python script manually, does *that* work? 3. If you put something blatantly syntactically incorrect in the Python program and then run the shell script, do you get an error message?

Comment: @TurePålsson 1. Yes, I am definitely running the right shell script. I can even check with the `which` command. 2. Yes. 3. No....

Comment: @TurePålsson Although if I run `bash test.sh` from the command line, I see the print statement and the error message

Comment: What happens if you change `/usr/bin/bash` to `/bin/bash`? What `which bash` returns?

Comment: I can't reproduce the issue. I'm thinking `test.sh` is not running the right script. Try `./test.sh`. Confirm with `type test.sh`; avoid `which`.

Answer (score 0):

My python output was missing when assigning it to a bash variable. I can't replicate your exact issue either, but I think this could help:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

script_return=$(python test.py)
echo "$script_return"
```